# Configure Rails 3 for S3 bucket using fog.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, fog

I have this Rails 3.2 application passed on from the previous freelancer in my company. I would like to know as to how to configure this existing S3 bucket to my new EC2 Instance.
Access to AWS is configured in fog.yml by using fog gem as well as carrierwave gem.

What am I missing in this fog.yml file

```
Fog.credentials_path = Rails.root.join('config/fog.yml')


CarrierWave.configure do |config|  
config.fog_credentials = {  
  }  
config.fog_directory  = "directory-name"  
 config.fog_public     = false  
config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}
end
```

Comment: Your question may not be specific enough to get a good answer here on StackOverflow. You may want to post for help in a place like Airpair or Codementor where someone can walk you through the process. Alternatively, ask something more specific and then we can help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#config/initializers/carrierwave.rb
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'aws_key',
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'aws_secret'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'bucket1'
  config.fog_host       = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com'
  config.fog_public     = true
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}
end

#app/uploader/image_uploader.rb
def store_dir
  "images/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}"
end

#app/views/pictures/show.html.erb
<%= image_tag @picture.image_url if @picture.image? %>`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at these examples:

http://fog.io/about/getting_started.html

It looks like the format is basically:

```
development:
  aws_access_key_id: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  aws_secret_access_key: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  provider: 'AWS'
test:
  aws_access_key_id: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  aws_secret_access_key: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  provider: 'AWS'

# set these environment variables on your prod server
production:
  aws_access_key_id: <%= ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] %>
  aws_secret_access_key: <%= ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] %>
  provider: 'AWS'
```

Make sure to use spaces rather than tabs since it's a YAML file.